# How to think about topological embeddings

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is injective. Then $f$ is an embedding if $f|_{f(X)}: X \rightarrow f(X)$ is a homeomorphism. At the moment my intuition is that $Y - f(X)$ might not "behave nicely", and only parts of $Y$ topologically resemble $X$. Is there some geometric picture one should have in mind when thinking about embeddings? Further, why do we require that $f$ be injective, is this just to satisfy the bijectivity of a homeomorphism?

Comment: If it isn't injective, then $X\to f(X)$ is certainly not a homeomorphism, so it is a redundant requirement, but probably included because our first intuition of what "embedding" means is an injection. The reason injection is not enough is to consider the function: $f:[0,1)\to \mathbb C$ sending $x\mapsto e^{2i\pi x}.$

Comment: It's unclear what you want to say about $Y\setminus f(X),$ but it is possible foe $X$ to be Hausdorff, and $Y\setminus f(X)$ not, or $X$ to be a manifold, but not $Y\setminus f(X).$ Nothing about $Y$ of $Y\setminus X$ can be really said.

Comment: One interesting example is if you have two topologies, $\tau_1, \tau_2$ on the same set $X.$ The identity function $(X,\tau_1)\to (X,\tau_2)$ is continuous if and only if $\tau_2\subseteq \tau_1,$ but is an embedding only when $\tau_2=\tau_1.$

Comment: In general, an injection need not be an embedding. But there is a theorem: If $X$ is a compact space and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then an injection is an embedding.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for all these helpful comments! Could you elaborate on what you mean by our first intuition of an embedding is an injection? For example, intuitively I can imagine $x^2$ being embedded into $\mathbb{R}^2$ but it certainly is not injective. I fear I may have the wrong picture in mind.

Comment: $x^2$ is not a topological space. I have no idea what you mean? As a function, it is a map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,$ so $\mathbb R^2$ has nothing to do with it. The *graph* of $x^2$ is an embedding, sending $x\mapsto (x,x^2).$ Indeed, if $f: X\to Y,$ is continuous, fhe graph embedding $X\to X\times Y$ sending $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ is always an embedding of $X$ into $X\times Y.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes I meant the graph of $x^2$, I should have specified my apologies. But my point was why is injectivity seen as an intuitive feature for an embedding to have.

Comment: But the graph of $x^2$ (1) an embedding of $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R^2,$ and (2) by a map, $x\mapsto (x,x^2),$ which is injective.  The map $x\mapsto x^2$ is, on the other hand, not an embedding of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R.$ It is unclear what you are trying to say. I guess intuitions depend on the person, and how you take the word "embedded" outside math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's no reason for the part of $Y$ outside of $f(X)$ to look anything like $X$; e.g. $Y$ could be the disjoint union of $X$ and another arbitrary topological space. For a more complicated example where $X$ is dense you could take $X = \mathbb{N}$ and $Y = \beta \mathbb{N}$ to be the [Stone-Cech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#The_Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification_of_the_natural_numbers), which is the space of [ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter_(set_theory)) on $\mathbb{N}$. The complement $\beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is quite complicated; you can check the links for more.

For a nice geometric picture you can think about a circle embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example, or a sphere or torus embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

And yes, $f$ has to be injective for $X \to f(X)$ to be a homeomorphism.